# Unit-testing event-triggered behaviour

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I have been using a pattern for some time. And I wonder if I am doing the right thing. I have a controller class that listens for events, and executes a private method when the event is raised. It goes a little something like this:

```
public class MyController
{

    public MyController(IMyEventRaiser eventRaisingObject)
    {
        eventRaisingObject.MyEvent += HandleEvent;
    }

    private void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // SOME STUFF I WANT TO TEST!!
    }
}


public class EventRaisingClass : IMyEventRaiser
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;
}
```

The only way to test the code in MyController.HandleEvent is to create a stub:IMyEventRaiser that raises the code.

I am not sure if this design is proper. On the one hand, I want to keep the HandleEvent method private, in order to illustrate that only an event can trigger it. On the other hand, it the private method contains key business logic, so I feel like it should be public or at least internal, which will also make it a lot easier to unit-test.

What do You lot think?

Regards, 
Morten

Comment: Why not use private accessors, (i.e. reflection) to test your private method just like any other private method?

Comment: This is an unknown procedure to me. Will definitely look it up :-)

Comment: There's nothing improper about what you're doing. One comment though: you probably need a *mock*, or even a *fake*, but not a *stub*. Normally, a stub doesn't do anything and cannot trigger any events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you've got sounds like a (mild) violation of [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Your controller both responds to events and holds the complicated logic that is executed for a particular event.  What if your controller were simply to dispatch the necessary data to a dedicated Processor that did the real work?  That Processor's method would necessarily be public - and therefore testable!  Isn't it nice how TDD points out SRP violations?

Comment: Ah, so you say that I am both controlling AND mediating at the same time? And that I should consider splitting the two, where the controlling part - that i now execute in a private method - should be in a class of its own?

Comment: Possibly so.  I'm saying it's worth considering the split.

Comment: What if the eventhandler is responsible to change the status of the Controller itself? e.g. some return value of public properties. Then it's OK to mock a event trigger and "test the internal"? Or should look for a better alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into Mocking Frameworks? "Moq" supports raising an event from a mocked type:

```
Mock<IMyEventRaiser> mock = new Mock<IMyEventRaiser>()
mock.Raise(e => e.MyEvent, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I do. But what do you think of the pattern in general? :-)

Comment: @Morten I generally don't like relying on an event to be triggered, but your implementation looks just fine and is perfectly legitimate.